# Translating cookies from localhost serving wsgi server to nginx reverse proxy

Tags: cookies, nginx, reverse-proxy, paster

I have nginx setup to front a python paste instance. They are on the same box with paste serving from 127.0.0.1 and nginx serving to outside world.

The problem comes when my python app sets cookies, the domain stays with localhost rendering the cookies useless. Obviously I'm not the first to encounter this, but I'm having trouble finding the standard solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [proxy_cookie_domain](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cookie_domain) directive is exists exactly for this case.

But it most likely that you do not pass the `Host` header.

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

http://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header

Comment: Thanks - just having trouble setting proxy_cookie_path now: I have proxy_cookie_path / /somewhere/myapp/ under location /somewhere/myapp. But the client still gets '/'.

Comment: Strange. How do you check it? Try `curl -I`.